# Two versions of slick.js (1.5 and 1.9) how to use each file in sperate sections of a web page, possable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add another slick slider that needs ver 1.9 and someone already has used a gallery slick slider at the top of the page with ver 1.5.
Now if I update the ver to the new one it breaks the gallery at the top and it does not look right.
If I use the old ver on my slick carousel it is not responsive and looks terrible.
Can I target each js file to the individual div's / id's?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like that, with some adjustements depending of how Slick is implemented, you will have to look at their source code, but you get the idea :

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="slickv1.js"></script>
<script>
   window.slickv1 = Slick
   window.Slick = null
</script>

<script src="slickv2.js"></script>

<script>
   window.slickv2 = Slick
   window.Slick = null  
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I add that what you are trying to achieve is a bad practise. I think you will spend less time to adjust the Slider of your colleague to use the new version of Slick rather then trying to use multiple versions of Slick.